# Setting the rails cache store for fragment_caching to be different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fragment-caching

Is is possible to configure the rails fragment caching to be a file_store and have the Rails.cache object to store values using a memory store? Or are they both the same storage mechanism in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, without monkey patching things, they're going to have to share the same cache store.

I'd assume it's possible to monkey patch things to have it look for which store to use elsewhere, and then get the two working separately, but that sounds like a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: Sounds about right. Or just set the cache store to :file and then make your own caching mechanism for key and value stores using Redis and your own class. Thank you :)